# get all combination of consecutive elements of string array while keeping the remaining elements C#

Tags: c#, string, search, combinations

i'm new in programming and i have a difficult time with the following task.

I have a string let's say `string final_word="Bacliff New Texas United States";` and i want to do the following:

1st check for the entire string in a databases, if a match exists i'm ok if not
I want to search for the substring `"Bacliff New Texas United"`.

If a match is found i'll search for the substring `"States"`, if not I'll search for the substring `"New Texas United States"`, if a match is found search for the substring `"Bacliff"`.

If not, search for the substring `"Bacliff New Texas"`.if a match is found search for the substring `"United States"` and if no matches are found for the last substring search for the substrings `"United"`and `"States"`.

Else search for the substring `"New Texas United"`, now if a match is found i will search the database for two individual substrings `"Bacliff"` and `"States"`, because i want all the substrings to be sequential words in the original string. and i will keep looking in the same way. If no matches found for each combination of two words, i will search each word individual.

In short,

First i have to search for the entire string

Second, search for substring with 5 words but keep the others in case a match is found for the first substring.

Third, search for sunstrings with 4 consecutive words and keep the others with respect to the original position.

Next search for substrings with 3 consequtive words etc..

At last search for each individual word.

if at some point a match is found for any combination of words, i will store this word and keep looking in the same ways for the other combinations..

I hope i made my point clear..
any help would be truly appreciated....

Thank you in advance.........

Comment: which database are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your input string into an array, then re-join the sub-arrays of consecutive words:

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string full = "Bacliff New Texas United States";
        // split the string in words
        string[] words = full.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        // get substrings 'size' words long
        for (int size = 1; size <= words.Length; ++size) {
            string[] destination = new string[size];
            for (int start = 0; start <= words.Length - size; ++start) {
                Array.Copy(words, start, destination, 0, size);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", destination));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

Sorry, I'm not 100% sure if I understood correctly what you want :)
Is this more like it?

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        string full = "Bacliff New Texas United States";
        // split the string in words
        string[] words = full.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        for (int size = 1; size < words.Length; ++size) {
            // get substrings of 'size' words
            for (int start = 0; start <= words.Length - size; ++start) {
                string[] before = new string[start];
                string[] destination = new string[size];
                string[] after = new string[words.Length - (size + start)];
                Array.Copy(words, 0, before, 0, before.Length);
                Array.Copy(words, start, destination, 0, destination.Length);
                Array.Copy(words, start + destination.Length, after, 0, after.Length);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} % {1} % {2}",
                    string.Join(" ", before),
                    string.Join(" ", destination),
                    string.Join(" ", after));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you..this function provides me with all the combination but have you any idea where to hold the remaining substrings??eg. if i find a match for the substring "Unites States" i want to check the remaining substring "Bacliff New Texas" following the same principles..

Comment: See edited answer... I hope I understood correctly what you are asking for now :)

Comment: that would do !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!thank you very much for your help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!now i need to figure out only some few details regarding the conditions to exist the loop..

Comment: @katerina: glad it helps :) If this is useful, then please vote it up and/or mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: @katerina: I think that you need a certain reputation to vote answers up, but don't worry :) I was specifying that only because I thought you are a new user

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Ms SQL then better use Full Text Search

Comment: thank you..my problem isn't how to ask the database but how can i produce all these substrings..